# UDP packets sent by Android application over wifi sometimes not received by android devices

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have built a client-server application in Android(Compiling with java-6) to send and receive udp packets.

My client code is as follow:

```
DatagramSocket socket =new DatagramSocket();  
socket.setBroadcast(true);  
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(dgram, dgramLength, host, port);
socket.send( packet );  
socket.close();
```

My server code is as follows:

```
DatagramSocket socket =new DatagramSocket(this.port);    
byte[] data=new byte[512];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length) ;     
// Wait for a response from the server   
try  
{  
   socket.receive(packet) ;    
}  
catch (Exception e)  
{}
```

The issue that I am facing is that when I am working on a wired network then all the sent packets are being received by master properly but when I am running the same code over wifi then sometimes sent packets are being received and sometimes not. I want to know that whether it is the general behavior of a wifi network or not.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: UDP is an *unreliable* protocol, and *will* have packet loss and reordering. If you want a safe protocol either use TCP or implement TCP-like features on top of UDP.

Comment: My packets are being received properly over UDP when I am on a wired network through usb to LAN adapter for android devices  but not on wireless network. Packets are sent properly as I am receiving the packets without any loss on a windows based machine i.e Zotac E-450. I have tested the android code on LG-P880 mobile, Sony Experia Z2 and MINITV for Android but none is working fine on a wireless network as they sometimes don't receive the packet

Comment: Maybe the wired LAN is more reliable and less prone to drop packets than the WiFi connection?

Comment: But the new thing that I have observed is that on android systems  wi-fi is dropping the packets but  the windows machine that was zotac E-450 in my case is receiving packets on the wi-fi properly. The thing that I am unable to deduce Is that is this due to hardware issue or the android OS.